# Im getting a unknown database error when i try to connect to my database nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome-extension

im creating a chrome extension and i keep getting this error

```
  code: 'ER_BAD_DB_ERROR',
  errno: 1049,
  sqlState: '42000',
  sqlMessage: "Unknown database 'blinkyblinky'",
  sql: undefined
```

below is the code I'm using

```
const mysql = require('mysql2');

const connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    port: 3306,
    database: 'blinkyblinky'
});

connection.query('SELECT * FROM userdata',
    function(err, results, fields) {
        console.log(err);
        console.log(results);
        console.log(fields);
    }
);
```

this is the database I'm trying to connect to
[image: this is the database I'm trying to connect to]

Comment: I don't see a password in your connection? Are you sure the database server you've added in the screenshot is running on port `3306`?

Comment: Are you sure, database `blinkyblinky` is created?

Comment: @PankajTanwar yes i have check multiple times

Answer (score -3):

so i was checking many thing i even create a db and a table and inserted values into it with javascript and it worked but when i checked locahost phpmyadmin none of the db i created was there i was like what hell so when i double check apparently it had been creating in my mysql workbench